# Looping an OpenCV image inside a Tkinter label - using an esp32-cam

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tkinter, urllib

It's a loop understanding problem, I'm new to Tkinter and I don't know how the images are updated

°°°PROBLEM°°°

It is about making a program that captures images of the ***esp32-cam*** module and can visualize and use them with the ***urllib*** and ***Opencv*** libraries, in addition to displaying the images in ***Tkinter*** to make a user interface

***The image updates correctly but scrolls down as shown in the images***

I would like you to help me with the problem and how to anchor it where I want, use the function .place (x = 0, y = 0) in and out of the loop but the image was not updating

°°°IMAGES°°°

starting the program, the image is centered in the Tkinter window, that's fine.
[first capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vyeqt.png)

when the image is refreshed at 500 milliseconds, the image is scrolled down "infinitely", as shown in the following image:
[second capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/figdT.png)

```
#Python v3.8.4

import tkinter as * 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib.request

url='http://192.168.0.24/picture'
delay = 1000

imgtk = [None]

def loopCapture():
    imgResponse = urllib.request.urlopen (url)
    imgNp =np.array(bytearray(imgResponse.read()),dtype=np.uint8)
    image = cv2.imdecode (imgNp, -1)

    b,g,r = cv2.split(image)
    img = cv2.merge((r,g,b))
    im = Image.fromarray(img)
    imgtk[0] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = im)
    capture = Label(root, image = imgtk[0]).pack()
    root.after(delay, loopCapture)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1200x700")
loopCapture()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you try to destroy the old Label first and then create and pack an newer on your window?

Comment: For this you need to separate your layout management from your inisilization and keep a reference somewhere.

Comment: You recreate new labels in each execution of `loopCapture()`.  You need to create once outside the function and update it in the function.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to learn more about the tkinter library, but if anyone comes across the same question, here is the code:

capture when running the program.
[image]

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import urllib.request
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import cv2

# esp32-cam url 
urlCam ='http://192.168.0.24/picture' 

panel = None
root = None

def loopCamera():
    imgResponse = urllib.request.urlopen (urlCam)
    imgNp = np.array(bytearray(imgResponse.read()),dtype=np.uint8)
    image = cv2.imdecode (imgNp, -1)

    b,g,r = cv2.split(image)
    img = cv2.merge((r,g,b))
    
    im = Image.fromarray(img)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = im)
    
    panel.configure(image = imgtk)
    panel.image = imgtk
    panel.after(5, loopCamera)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('car-vision')
root.geometry('1000x600')

panel = tk.Label(root)
panel.pack()
loopCamera()
root.mainloop()
```